# Install multiple homebrew formulas at the same time

Tags: unix, homebrew, io-redirection

You can install multiple homebrew formulas by `brew install package1 package2`. But if you have a text file with all the packages that you would like to install. How would you do it?

`brew install < packages.txt` doesn't work. It gives me the response: `This command requires a formula argument`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Like this:

```
brew install $(cat packages.txt)
```

or even just

```
brew install $(<packages.txt)
```

Comment: It only allowed me to install cask packages. Is this behaviour expected? I made a list with git, openjdk and ssh-copy-id, none of which are cask packs. It still installed Homebrew-Cask and threw an error that it cant find a cask pack called "git"

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't set on doing the .txt file I would just set it up using the `\` character to break a single line command across multiple lines, which you can then just copy & paste.

Simple and easy to maintain and expand.

Example:

```
brew install \
formulae1 \
formulae2 \
formulae3 \
...
```

Which would install formulae1, formulae2, formulae3, ... etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an [alternative one-line approach](https://benjamin-rood.gitbooks.io/punching-myself-in-the-face/content/2018/brew-search-and-install-in-one-line.html), which bypasses the need to create a file as an in-between step:

#### Syntax:

```
brew install $( brew search my-search-term | grep my-filter-term | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

*vs.*

```
brew search x | grep y > install_list.txt
brew install $( < install_list.txt )
```

*Alternative (using awk):*

```
brew search x | awk '/inclusion string/ && !/exclusion string/' | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

---

#### Example:

Suppose I wanted to install all the Nerd Fonts not currently on my machine in one go.

`brew search fonts` will give multiple rows in results – similar to the default output from `ls`:

```
brpro ➜ ~ brew search font
==> Partial Matches
birdfont                       font-hack-nerd-font
dfontsplitter                  font-hack-nerd-font-mono
font-3270 font-halant          font-noto-sans-tibetan
font-3270-nerd-font ✔          font-hammersmith-one
font-3270-nerd-font-mono ✔     font-han-nom-a
font-abeezee font-hanalei      font-noto-sans-vai
(...)
```

Piping the output to `grep -i nerd` gives a single line-separated list of only the *taps* we want.

```
brpro ➜ ~ brew search font | grep -i nerd
font-3270-nerd-font
font-3270-nerd-font-mono
font-anonymouspro-nerd-font
font-anonymouspro-nerd-font-mono
font-arimo-nerd-font
font-arimo-nerd-font-mono
font-aurulentsansmono-nerd-font
(...)
```

We can use `tr` to convert this output to a whitespace-separated single line:

```
brpro ➜ ~ brew search font | grep nerd | tr '\n' ' '
font-3270-nerd-font font-3270-nerd-font-mono font-anonymouspro-nerd-font font-anonymouspro-nerd-font-mono (...)
```

Now we just need to pass the result to `brew install`:

```
brew install $( brew search font | grep nerd | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

Pipes! Composition! Joy!

*La voie Unix!*

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth mentioning that Brew has its own file format to specify a list of packages to install: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle

Here is a nice write up on the topic: https://medium.com/@satorusasozaki/automate-mac-os-x-configuration-by-using-brewfile-58a78ce5cc53

Answer (score 0):

Used `Benjamin R`s answer and encountered an issue, so leaving this here for others.

Running

```
brew install $( brew cask search font-nerd | grep font-nerd | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

first gave me

```
Error: Calling `brew cask search` is disabled! Use `brew search` instead.
```

then

```
Error: No available formula with the name "font-3270-nerd-font"
```

so I had to remove `cask` from search but add it to the install like this

```
brew cask install $( brew search font-nerd | grep font-nerd | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

and it installed everything in one go.

You may want to omit mono versions of those fonts since they just have smaller icon sizes.

```
brew cask install $( brew search nerd-font | awk '/nerd-font/ && !/-mono$/' | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

Comment: Cheers! Next time just feel free to edit my answer, `brew cask search ...` used to be valid but they removed it as a necessity.

Comment: Oh, right. I wanted to just add a comment but I don't have enough reputation :) Didn't check if I could edit.